# Getting odd array Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

Getting a very odd error on a specific users phone with my mobile app that has not happened on any other phone.  Its been installed on dozens and dozens of Android and iPhones - but this one users phone is turning up the most bizarre error:

On this line in a .controller,

> [$scope.rides,$scope.filter] = Rides.refresh()

The user's phone is getting the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

I am lucky because I know who the user is and she brought her phone to my house where I am able to use Chrome Inspector dev console to see the app locally install on her phone and generate this error.  What worries me is how many other phones is this happening on.  But for the life of me I don't understand why this code works on my phone Samsung 5S and not on her Samsung 5S (both are models: SM-G900T).  The app and the above code works just fine for me on my phone in both developer mode as well as Play Store compiled version....but both developer mode and Play Store compile version do not work on her phone.

Comment: I just looked further into her phone...she is running version 5.1.1 and I am running version 6.0.1.  Obviously, there is an issue with the older version 5.1.1...but why is this an issue at all?  Why is her version 5.1.1 seeing that var assignment as invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Once I clued into the version of Android my user was on (5.1.1) I was able finally track down the issue.  Turns out Chrome on Android 5.x and lower does not support deconstructed array assignments, this handy chart helps show what ECMAScript features are available (and not available) in all the various versions of browsers on almost all platforms:  http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/